# Estimating mean and confidence interval for "stairs up, elevator down" time series

Tags: regression, machine-learning, time-series, stationarity, finance

I have a time series which exhibits the classic "stairs up, elevator down" pattern of financial time series, i.e. slow rises up and quick drops. Given this series, I wanted to predict the next point as well as it's associated 95% confidence interval.
Any thoughts on algorithms to use here? [image: Time Series]

Comment: Have you tried ARMA yet?

Comment: Thanks @RichardHardy Not yet, will try ARMA but wanted to generate a list of a few different approaches first.